# GIF viewer for 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gif, image-viewers

I tried to view a GIF through image viewer. It says, not supported. What do I need to view GIFs in 16.04 ?

Update :

I used " Peek " to generate screen cast. Firefox too failed to open it. Seems like a file issue. Thanks.

Comment: If you can't view the .gif file with the default image viewer it may be corrupt or something the command `file filename.gif` may rpovide some insight.

Answer (score 3):

The default Image Viewer application in Ubuntu supports the gif image format. If Image Viewer does not open your .gif image, there may be something wrong with the .gif file.

You can split up the .gif into multiple image files using imagemagick in order to take a closer look at what the gif file is made of.

```
cd /path/to/directory/containing/input-file.gif
convert -coalesce input-file.gif output%05d.png
```

ImageMagick can also put a .gif file back together.

```
convert -delay 300 -loop 0 *.png animation.gif
```

ImageMagick has options to change the size and timing of the output .gif file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open it with firefox for example , if it doesn't open then the .gif file probably is **corrupted** .